# generate graphql typedef string from introspected schema

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I have a resulting JSON file of the introspected schema, is there an easy way to:

1. Ingest that using graphql-js?
2. Convert it to the string literal style of typedef?

So:

```
   {
     "data": {
       "__schema": {
         "queryType": {
           "name": "Query"
         },
         "types": {
         {
           "kind": "OBJECT",
           "name": "UserNode",
           "description": "",
           "fields": [
           {
             "name": "firstName",
             "description": "",
             "args": [],
             "type": {
               "kind": "SCALAR",
               "name": "String",
               "ofType": null
            },
            "isDeprecated": false,
            "deprecationReason": null
          },
          ...
   }
```

would become:

```
   schema {
     query: Query
   }

   user {
     firstName: String
   }
   ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a GraphQL server running (rather than just the json schema), then you can do this with [`gqlschema`](http://dev.apollodata.com/tools/graphql-tools/generate-schema.html) from Apollo's graphql-tools:

```
gqlschema http://localhost:3000/graphql -t
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40876985/are-there-any-tools-to-dynamically-generate-graphql-schema-string).