# Are there any tools to dynamically generate graphQl schema string?

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js

I will have JSON from a CMS and using the JSON I want to be able to programmatically write a graphQl schema. Without needing to write the string directly.

Are there any JavaScript tools to do this?

I am referring to the string argument to the buildSchema function:

http://graphql.org/code/

Comment: How would you know which fields/types were optional or not?

Answer (score 2):

The `json-graphql-server` project does that: Take a data JSON as input, infer types and fields from the data, write a schema containing types, queries and mutations, and start a GraphQL server schema based on that.

https://github.com/marmelab/json-graphql-server

I know of another tool that does just the JSON to schema part, but it does not generate queries or mutations:

https://github.com/aweary/json-to-graphql

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how does your JSON files look like.
For me I had a similar case - a kind of complex json definition file - and I built my own json to graphql-js converter [here](https://github.com/shalkam/gql-fhir/blob/master/src/data/fhir/helpers/gql-schema/index.js)

- After building your server you can generate the schema string in `.graphql` file using this package [gql-tools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gql-tools), using this command - after launching the server - :-

  `gqlschema http://localhost:3000/graphql -t`
- Use the schema string along with [graphql-server-express](http://graphql.org/code/#graphql-server-http-dev-apollodata-com-tools-graphql-server-index-html-github-https-github-com-apollostack-graphql-server-npm-https-www-npmjs-com-package-graphql-server) from apollo  and link it with [resolvers](http://dev.apollodata.com/tools/graphql-tools/generate-schema.html#makeExecutableSchema)